# Error while building Cordova-WP8 Project in Command line (Cordova-3.5)

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am building mobile app with the help of cordova 3.5 command line interface. I installed windows8, wp8, android and firfox-os in my app.
I am able to build android and firefox-os. But when I am trying to build windows8 or wp8, the error displayed as:

```
C:\Users\igs\hello>cordova build wp8
Running command: C:\Users\igs\hello\platforms\wp8\cordova\build.bat

WARNING: [ --debug | --release ] not specified, defaulting to debug...
Cleaning cordova project...
Building Cordova-WP8 Project:
        Configuration : Debug
        Directory : C:\Users\igs\hello\platforms\wp8
toolsVersion 0 is not supported
        MSBuildToolsPath: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
buildCommand = %comspec% /c ""C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbu
ild" "C:\Users\igs\hello\platforms\wp8\HelloWorld.sln" /clp:NoSummary;NoIt
emAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal /nologo /p:Configuration=Debug"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\igs\hello\platforms\wp8\HelloWorld.csproj(192,5): error MSB4019:
The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v8.0
\Microsoft.WindowsPhone.v8.0.Overrides.targets" was not found. Confirm that the
path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Error: C:\Users\igs\hello\platforms\wp8\cordova\build.bat: Command failed
with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\igs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Is anything need to be installed? please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just having the exact same problem...

Comment: I was Having the same problem yesteday...

I was trying the grunt build at first, All I did was removed the wp8 platform then
**cordova platform add windows, 
cordova build windows**

Then I was able to make a build successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. Could it be possible that you've updated to cordova 4? I've realized the problem after doing so.

@Dev creating a windows project works, but creating a wp8 is still a problem. When using "cordova platform remove wp8" you can add wp8 as a platform, but when building a wp8 project it produces the same error.

I think in my case its the problem that cordova is refering to Program Files (x86) and I don't have that folder (just "Programme (x86)"). Maybe you've got the same problem.

You could also google for "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v8.0
\Microsoft.WindowsPhone.v8.0.Overrides.targets", there are some stackoverflow articles about this topic already, so you might find a solution there.

Comment: After building windows yesterday (cordova platform add windows, cordova build windows), it worked to just use "cordova build" (building wp8 itself doesnt work). Programme(x86) is considered as C:\Program Files (x86) - false attempt :(. The problem is caused by the missing WindowsPhone folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft. I'm not quite sure if you can resolve it, by installing the windows phone sdk (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html). Unfortunately I can't test it, as I'm not allowed to install software on this computer.